# Arduino Google speech api

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c++

I'm currently experimenting with my arduino Uno. I control it via an mobile (android) but wanted to just use a microphone on the board so I don't need to carry my mobile around. It is possible to record flac files from a mic and send it to Google speech api and get a return? And then maybe output it via the synthesis.

So it is possible to do this on an arduino uno and with C. If doesnt is there any other way I can go? I could buy a raspberry pi but I don't an whole operating system like linux installed. So any thoughts?

Comment: The Uno has only 2k of RAM so I doubt you will be able to record anything much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a special voice recognition shield (for example: [EasyVR Shield 3.0 - Voice Recognition Shield](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13316)) to integrate a simple and basic voice recognition. I think it's a very fast and easy prototyping way...

For the use of the more complex Google Speech Recognition I would use a more powerful microcontroller (such as Raspberry PI or something like that)...